# Making Grid Layout with items in diagonally placed

Tags: html, css, grid

[This is what i want to achieve , first i want to position the entire grid and then place the items in the grid diagonally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWSb8.png)

HTML Code:

```
<body>
    <div class="svg-bg"> 
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nesciunt, voluptatibus.</div>
            <div class="Info" >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Suscipit </div>
            <button class="switch"><a href="second.html">Lets Start</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
.header{
    color: whitesmoke;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-row-start: 1;
}

.Info{
    font-size: 3.5rem;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    color: whitesmoke;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
}

.wrapper{
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(100px,1fr));
    grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(10px,1fr));
    gap: 2rem;
}

.switch{
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-row-start: 3;
}
.svg-bg{
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: none;
    background-image: url("circle-scatter-haikei.svg");
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I am new to grid layouts, Is there a method by which i can specify the size of the whole grid?

Comment: You can set an height to wrapper , example `.wrapper {min-height:100vh;}` and eventually give a `margin-block:auto;` to the elements dispatched into the grid.

Comment: But how do i place the element in the grid diagonally and how to i position the entire grid itself?

Answer (score 0):

For diagonally placement, grid should be in equal height and width. So, we can simplyfy the style of `wrapper` class.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);
```

Also, if you want to place the first and third div content in the center than add these styles `wrapper` class.

```
align-items: center;      
justify-items: center;
```

And as per the screenshot you are looking for the entire grid positioning which can be easily achieved by adding following styles in the `wrapper` class.

```
width: 70vw; margin-left:auto;
```

CSS changes for the `wrapper` class will be:

```
.wrapper{
    justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(3,1fr);
    gap: 2rem;
    width: 70vw; 
    margin-left:auto;
    align-items: center;      
    justify-items: center;
}
```